# How do you search varchar variables in varchar column ? PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to find if some given responsibilities in Oracle 11g exist in database or not.

Let's say we have 10 responsibilities and I want to search if they exist in the database that contains 60.

How do you search varchar variables in varchar column ?

For single variable it should be easy..

```
declare
var varchar(100);
begin
var:='&var';
if var is not null 
then
select responsibility_name  FROM  apps.fnd_responsibility_tl where responsibility_name  _ ?
dbms_output.put_line(var||' EXISTS'); 
else
dbms_output.put_line(var||' ERROR'); 
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this in PL/SQL and not SQL? Wouldn't `SELECT * FROM apps.fnd_responsibility_tl WHERE reponsibility_name IN ('r1','r2','r3','etc');` suffice?

Comment: It would be enough if it would return every responsibility and a error message or a exist message too. Btw,is it difficult to implement in PL/SQL?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but it's usually undesirable to use PL/SQL over SQL for problems that can be solved in SQL as it adds unnecessary overhead and complexity. What format is your list of 10 responsibilities in? Is it in another table? Is it a comma separated list?

Comment: Hey Xvar,yes it's like a given column from an excel file and the responsibilities column from fnd_responsibility_tl. The thing is that when SQL searches for a varchar value using IN, it skips it if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this, the simple way, and the way that you request in your question using PL/SQL.

First, the simple way using just SQL. This uses a trick taken from [a blog post by Arunkumar Ramamoorthy](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement) to convert a comma separated list into rows using REGEXP_SUBSTR and CONNECT BY.

```
WITH  search_criteria AS (
   SELECT   TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('&search_criteria','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS search_responsibility
   FROM     dual
   CONNECT BY
            TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('&search_criteria', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT   s.search_responsibility,  
         CASE WHEN r.responsibility_name IS NULL THEN 'ERROR' ELSE 'EXISTS' END AS status
FROM     search_criteria s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
         apps.fnd_responsibility_tl r ON (r.responsibility_name = s.search_responsibility);
```

And secondly, the more complex way using PL/SQL and DBMS_OUTPUT. This uses the same principles as the SQL version but uses a cursor to check if each responsibility exists, outputting either an EXISTS or ERROR message.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_responsibilities (p_search_criteria IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  CURSOR c_responsibilities (p_responsibilities IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
   SELECT   TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_responsibilities,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS search_responsibility
   FROM     dual
   CONNECT BY
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_responsibilities, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

   lv_temp  apps.fnd_responsibility_tl.responsibility_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
   FOR c IN c_responsibilities(p_search_criteria)
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         SELECT   r.responsibility_name
         INTO     lv_temp
         FROM     apps.fnd_responsibility_tl r
         WHERE    r.responsibility_name = c.search_responsibility;

         dbms_output.put_line(c.search_responsibility || ' EXISTS');
      EXCEPTION 
         WHEN no_data_found THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(c.search_responsibility || ' ERROR');
      END;
   END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: Wow.Let me admire this.

Comment: I have tested the SQL version. It returned more responsibilities with the same name. Solved by adding SELECT DISTINCT instead SELECT.Thank you Xvar! I would give a vote if I could :)

Comment: Ah yes if there can be multiple responsibilities with the same name that'll happen. You should be able to mark my answer as accepted even if you can't vote by the way, since you're the question asker.